# WebView background transparent using modelviewer

Tags: android, css, kotlin, webview, transparent

I am using modelviewer to show a 3d model on a webview in kotlin android studio. The problem is when i load the object the background shows white.
I have css with background-color:transparent and when it shows ignore the css.

Anyone knows how to do it?

modelViewer.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:transparent">
<!-- Import the component -->
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/focus-visible@5.0.2/dist/focus-visible.js" defer></script>
<model-viewer
    orbit-sensitivity="2"
    interaction-prompt="none"
    id="reveal"
    camera-controls="true"
    auto-rotate="true"
    poster="https://test-aorist-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/images/artwork/900x600/187.1.jpg"
    src="https://test-aorist-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/models/artwork/187.1.glb"
    alt="Bold [3D]"
    ar-status="not-presenting"
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0; 
display: block; background-color: #ffffff;">
</model-viewer>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginActivity.kt

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)
    loadModel()
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
fun loadModel(){
    ModelWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    ModelWebView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
    ModelWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/modelViewer.html")
}
```

}

Result: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPRUO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, i didn't know that MV does render transparent itself so i started taking a look to webviewer and not to ModelViewer, i had to set transparent color putting on my LoginActivity.kt this line:
webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)